# How to restart ASP.NET Core 5.0 website after appsettings.json changed?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

The website is host on IIS, I hope it like asp.net website, auto restart when changed web.config or something else. please help.

Comment: You really want to restart the entire server or just reload the config?

Comment: @DavidG I want restart this app, not only reload config, because state is hard to manage, at the same time, I can afford restart cost.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, any better way?

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    ChangeToken.OnChange(configuration.GetReloadToken, lifetime.StopApplication);
    ...
}
```