# How to restart asp.net core published app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have a problem with changing appsettings.json on the asp.net core application that is published on the host, I want to change the settings and restart the app to use new settings. but I don't know how to restart the app.

in ASP.NET webforms, we change the web.config, and its forces the application to restart. but in asp.net core, it's not work.

how to restart the application when appsettings.json changes?

Comment: did you see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67105102/how-to-restart-asp-net-core-5-0-website-after-appsettings-json-changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You **can** still use `web.config` in IIS with ASP.NET Core... sort-of:

  - Even though ASP.NET Core doesn't use `web.config` files anymore, IIS still uses `web.config` to set IIS web-server settings (in `<system.webServer>`).
  - So adding even a stub `web.config` file, then making some insignificant change to it (I don't think `touch web.config` will work, though) then IIS will restart the website's application based in that virtual-dir or application-scope.

Comment: Thanks dude, yes I know about web.config in asp.net core, but unfortunately change the web.config, cant restart the app.

Comment: @mRizvandi It works for me; so let me ask you how exactly you're running your ASP.NET Core application under IIS? (ARR? Reverse-proxy? Are you certain you're actually using IIS and not nginx or running Kestrel directly or some other reverse-proxy?)

Comment: yes, its work, my mistake was we have to appsettings.json on projects. server side and client side, server side appsettings.json updated by changing web.config but blazor (client side) doesn't changed. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the app, and then reloading the page manually will run the app again.

```cs
public class StopApp
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _host;
    public StopApp(IHostApplicationLifetime host)
    {
        _host = host;
    }

    public class Stop()
    {
        _host.StopApplication();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question where they're asking how they can trigger an application restart just by editing files in the filesystem - perhaps if your answer used a  `FileSystemWatcher` to _then_ trigger `IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()` ?

Comment: @Dai yes you are right, I was not aware that the restart needed to be triggered automatically.